# HTML SVG map image follow path

Tags: html, svg, transform

I currently have an SVG file in HTML.

The SVG and viewbox is 500x500. I then have an Image element which is 2500x2500 (a large map).

In Illustrator I created a path which follows roads around the map.

```
<svg width="500px" height="500px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
    <image transform="translate(-430 -830)" id="mapImage" style="overflow:visible;" width="2562" height="2682" xlink:href="map.png" />
    <path transform="translate(-430 -830)" id="roadPath" d="M581.7,1030l..............."/>
</svg>
```

I have successfully got the 'road path' to animate using the following:

```
    var distancePerPoint = 1;
    var drawFPS          = 60;

    var orig = document.querySelector('path'), length, timer;

    function startDrawingPath(){
        length = 0;
        orig.style.stroke = '#f60';
        timer = setInterval(increaseLength,1000/drawFPS);
    }

    function increaseLength(){
        var pathLength = orig.getTotalLength();
        length += distancePerPoint;
        orig.style.strokeDasharray = [length,pathLength].join(' ');
        if (length >= pathLength) clearInterval(timer);
    }

    startDrawingPath();
```

However, because I'm only viewing 500x500px of the map the animated road goes outside the bounds fairly quickly. What I'm currently trying to do is get the Image element to move to the correct position in order to "follow" the road as it animates.

I think I need to do something with path.getPointAtLength(length) and then transform the Image with something like:

```
document.getElementById("mapImage").setAttribute("transform", "translate(??,??)");
```

but I'm not entirely sure how to work out the co-ordinates to plug in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just the difference between the path start coords (ie. at length=0) and the current path coords. But negated.

```
var  pathStart = path.getPointAtLength(0);

// Then as you move along the path...
var  currentPoint = path.getPointAtLength(length);
var  diffX = currentPoint.x - pathStart.x;
var  diffY = currentPoint.y - pathStart.y;
document.getElementById("mapImage").setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(-diffX)+","+(-diffY)+")");
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks very much